# A function differentiable on an open subset

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function differentiable on an open subset $U$. Let $a\in U$. If $f$ attains a maximum or a minimum at $a$, prove that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)=0$ for all $i$.

I seen a proof by contradiction, but it wasn't very intuitive for me. Can someone help provide a more direct, clearer proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you a proof if $f$ has a minimum in $a$. The proof for the maximum is similar. Since $f$ is differentiable $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+te_i)-f(a)}{t}$ exists. Furthermore, $f(a+te_i)-f(a)\ge0$ for all $t$ in a small enough neighborhood of $0$. Now let $t\nearrow0$. Then $\frac{f(a+te_i)-f(a)}{t}\le0$, since $t<0$, so $\lim_{t\nearrow 0}\frac{f(a+te_i)-f(a)}{t}\le0$. You can use the same argument (letting $t\searrow 0$) to show $\lim_{t\searrow 0}\frac{f(a+te_i)-f(a)}{t}\ge0$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+te_i)-f(a)}{t}=0$.

Comment: What does $t\nearrow0$ and $t\searrow 0$ mean? Also, why is $t<0$?

Comment: @Alex $t\nearrow 0$ means $t$ converges to $0$ from below, that is $t<0$ and $t\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Understand thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some intuition.  Since you used partial derivatives, I'll assume you meant a function with more than one argument.  If the partial derivative is not 0 in at least 1 coordinate direction, then this means the function is either increasing or decreasing in that direction (locally), which means that at that point, we cannot be a local max or a local min.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But I was looking for a more direct proof.